# content in div spills into div below

Tags: css

Can someone tell me why the contents of `page-view-count` & `num-of-days` div spills into `top-header` in my implementation?

**Markup:**

```
<div id="top-stats">
    <div id="page-view-count">count</div>
    <div id="num-of-days">num of days</div>
</div> 

<div id="top-header"This is a test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top-stats{
    width: 100%;
}

#page-view-count, #num-of-days{
    color: #666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#page-view-count{
    float:left;
}

#num-of-days{
    float:right;
}

#top-header{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#DBDB70;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

If I were to remove the `float` property it stacks up nicely inside `top-stats`.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greenpool/hMCMR/)

I'm probably missing some simple rule but I'm probably looking too closely and need another pair of eyes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#top-header{
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#DBDB70;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Kqrj/1/)